# Why might I be getting "task completion callback called too many times" in gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Given the following gulp task, why might I be getting the following error?

> Error: task completion callback called too many times

```
function myTask(options, cb) { // cb is the gulp cb
  var serverInstance = http.createServer(dispatch({ /*routes*/ }));

  serverInstance.listen(options.port, function() {
    cb(); // Stack trace identifies this line as throwing the error
  });
}

function partial(fn) {   
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return function() {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}

gulp.task('task-name', ['task-dependency'], partial(myTask, { port: 8080 }));
```

**Edit:**

The following modification makes it work (my question still remains however):

```
gulp.task('task-name', ['task-dependency'], function(cb) {
  partial(myTask, { port: 8080 })(cb);
});
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with gulp, but isn't it intended for carrying out builds? You seem to be using it to launch a server. And if you access that server more than once, the `cb()` callback is going to be called more than once.

Comment: Yes, at the end of this build task, a server is started that will deliver the application for testing purposes on a developer's machine.

Comment: @JLRishe the callback supplied is only invoked once when the listening event is raised by the server (IIUC) https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback

Comment: Could this problem be something to do with needing to supply gulp with hints as to the manner of task termination?

Comment: @JLRishe Not according to the http-server documentation. That callback should only be called a single time, when the server starts listening.

Comment: `return fn.bind(this, args);` instead of all code in the partial() ?

Comment: @eicto using `bind` will affect the receiver of the function, something I would like to avoid.

Comment: affect which way ? you trying to do almost the same doing `fn.apply(this,`

Comment: @eicto Rhetorical question: what is `this` in `fn.bind(this)`? I am supplying a callback to Gulp that it will invoke at some later time. I know little about Gulp and there may be a convention that `this` is set to a value determined by Gulp for use in the callback (e.g. `this` might be set to Gulp itself). Let me know if this sounds unreasonable.

Comment: ok, i see the mistake :) yes, your sync/async answer should be correct :) seems i sleepy enough just found where the gulp decide if it async or not more over my try was just hide the problem just because the arguments was are arrays this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because gulp uses heuristics (including the return value of the callback and whether it accepts a callback parameter) to detect async vs sync tasks, and it treats them differently accordingly. My partial function returns a function with no parameters declared that was tricking gulp into thinking it was synchronous when it was asynchronous.

Modifying `partial` to return a function with a single named parameter solved the issue.

```
//...
return function(cb) {
  return fn.apply(this, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
};
//...
```

Comment: If you use `.bind()` for your partial function application, it will create a function with the correct arity: `(function myTask(options, cb){}).bind(null, { port: 8080 }).length === 1`

Comment: Good point. My original avoidance of bind was because I did not want to affect the receiver of the function. Separately, is there a mechanism to change the arity of a function at runtime without using bind (or eval)? Is `length` writable, for example? Edit: no `length` is not writable

Comment: AFAIK, the only other option it is to use the function constructor, but that's pretty hacky. The syntax doesn't really give any clean option to dynamically indicate the number of parameters a created function has. lodash's `_.bind`, `_.curry`, and `_.partial` all return functions with arity 0.